# Adding a user as a tester in the facebook api asks for approval (pending). But doesn't ask for user permission if added via "Add Testers"

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to add a user as one of the testers of my facebook app.

1) If i try to add the user using the "Add Tester" section under "Roles", the user gets added perfectly fine and there's no need of approval from the user.

2) However, when I try to add the user by sending a post request to the /{app-id}/roles endpoint '{'user' : , 'role': 'testers'}', the user needs to approve this action and it shows up as (Pending).

I don't get this inconsistency, is there a work around for this?[This is what I see i.e "Pending"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAkHa.png)